# how to stop ASyncTask thread in android

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

```
can anybody have any idea how to stop ASyncTask thread in android?.
```

Actually i have a loop which creates threads and executes them. and when this loop will end i want to stop all that threads which have run.
is there anyway to stop threads?

thanks alot.

Comment: What makes you think that forking threads in a loop is a good idea in the first place?

Answer (score 40):

In my experience with `AsyncTask`, calling `cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning)` doesn't necessarily stop the execution of the background process.  All that seems to happen is that the `AsyncTask` will execute `onCancelled()`, and **won't** run `onPostExecute()` when it completes.  The behaviour probably depends on exactly what code you have in `doInBackgound()`

Comment: True. Check isCancelled() regularly in doInBackground() to see if you should stop the work and finish yourself.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I perform server requests with HttpPost, HttpGet and so on. The only way I found to end an AsyncTask was calling the abort() method as you can see in the following example

```
if (isCancelled) {
     try {
         //cancel the task and immediately abort the HttpRequest
         uploadTask.cancel(true);
         post.abort();
     } catch (UnsupportedOperationException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```