# How to speed up queries when a key is pressed in Suggesstion Dictionary

Tags: android, sqlite

The structure of DB Dictionary includes two columns: KEY and VALUE. When I press a key, it takes about 2s to finish finding suggestion keywords for my dictionary. But if a user presses 5 words continuous, what will happen. If I press a key, after that my queries is executed, but it causes  my Virtual keyboard to crash, cannot add a new key press until the query is completed. If I used UI thread, it will cause deadlock. Can anyone help me in this matter?

**UPDATE**: I combine the two methods: index and Thread with queues. I add a new word when press a key with queues. I query the order from the queue and delete its value in front of the queue. when the user press a key repeatedly, it will query the last element of the queue. And i used keyword **synchronized** to avoid errors **cursor index out of bounds "index -1 requested: with size 1024"** with multithread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your Key column is indexed, see the [SQLite CREATE INDEX](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html) page.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I used index but it ineffective. I think the solution is use thread but how to avoid deadlock

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are looking for locking the textbox or getting the data without crash?
If you use ajax with javascript i think you will get a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use a [AsyncTast](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for the query. This will reduce the impact on the UI thread. But you can't stop an AsyncTask abruptly, although you can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429043/how-to-stop-asynctask-thread-in-android).

Hope this gives you an idea to go ahead.