# How to Stop Asynch Task?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to stop ASyncTask thread in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429043/how-to-stop-asynctask-thread-in-android)

I have created an app which has an synch task doing something in the background. In my OnPostExecute function I created an intent to start an activity. The App is working perfectly fine till now. Now I wanted to stop that Asynch Task when the new actvity starts. How can I do that? Please help ......

Comment: you've obviously not bothered to make a google search

Comment: If the new activity starts in `OnPostExecute()`, then the `ASyncTask` *is already done* with the "async" part.

Comment: No its not like that...AsynchTask still running when new activity starts....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this

```
MyAsyncTask task = new MyAsyncTask();
task.cancel(true);
```

in your `onStop();`.

Answer (score 0):

**OnPostExecute()** method will only be called after `Completing DoInBackgroung() method`. so you asynctask will finish while you are going to another Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Your AsyncTask finishes after executing onPostExecute(), so you don't have to worry