# Stopping all asynctasks in Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to stop ASyncTask thread in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429043/how-to-stop-asynctask-thread-in-android)

Can I force all `AsyncTasks` in the stack to stop and let just UI thread run? 
I connect to network and download some info, images from server using AsyncTasks. But when the connection is lost, I need to stop them all. It is my application requirement.

Comment: What is your problem.....and why are you intended to stop all async tasks..?

Comment: Leave `Asynctask` alone

Comment: Refer to these post's on how to stop a AsyncTask



http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7821284/how-to-stop-asynctask-thread-in-android
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429043/how-to-stop-asynctask-thread-in-android

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have understood the proper use of AsyncTasks:

- When you want to download use a Service and store it in a database.
- Use AsyncTasks only when something is to be bound to the Activity/Fragment. Loading images to be displayed in the Activity/Fragment for instance.

I try to use Services as much as possible and have a callback to the Activity/Fragment that gets notified when my thing has been downloaded or similar.

Answer (score -1):

```
you can simply cancel your Async tasks

    new task().cancel();
```

Comment: task is name of your Async tasjk

Comment: Yes, i knew that. But maybe I can stop all stack somehow without cancelling every asyncTask individually?
Sure, i can put them all in a list and then iterate through.